# How to verify user email from mobile app Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I was using my website to verify the email of my users but since the email verification from firebase always redirect to the mobile app when you use a smartphone, i have to handle the link in-app.

To do so, i have followed the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#verifying-a-users-email) and i have also read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#handling_email_actions_in_a_mobile_application).
It should be working in theory, the only problem is that the `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()` only returns the link that **opened** the app.

Here is my code to validate the email :

```
final PendingDynamicLinkData? pendingLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    if (pendingLink != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = pendingLink.link;
      final String? actionCode = deepLink.queryParameters['oobCode'];
      try {
        await provideFirebaseAuth().checkActionCode(actionCode!);
        await provideFirebaseAuth().applyActionCode(actionCode);
        // If successful, reload the user:
        getCurrentUser()!.reload();
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-action-code') {
          LogManager.d('The code is invalid.');
        }
      }
    }
```

90% of the time, the email verification is sent when the user creates his account so he is still in the app and receive a mail, and then he :

- Put the app in background (`paused` state)
- Goes to his mailbox
- Clicks on the link
- Gets redirected back to the app

And unfortunately `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()` can't work in this situation as the app may not be killed.

Would `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink` work ? Or is there any other way to solve this please ?

PS : I know that there is a possible to add `handleCodeInApp: false` to the `user.sendEmailVerification(codeSettings)` to force redirect to the browser, but it simply doesn't work with the latest version of `firebase_auth: 3.3.9` and even in older versions so i have to handle it in app.  I have made an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7074) on GitHub about that few months ago already...

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8268) regarding `FirebaseDynamicLinks` that i have made.

EDIT :

To get the bounty, i would like the whole code from sending an email verification, until the `checkActionCode` call that handles the above use case please + when the app is terminated during the process.

EDIT 2 :

I have reached out Firebase support regarding this as it seems there are few bugs underneath.
Will post an answer once i have a concrete response for what is happening.